# $\sin \frac{1}{x}$ is not uniformly continuous on $[1, \infty]$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

$\sin \frac{1}{x}$ is not uniformly continuous on $[1, \infty]$

I was trying to come up with a counter example using sequence, but I could not find one.

Comment: Are you sure of the question?

Comment: Note that when $x$ is large, $\sin \frac 1x $ is more or less $\frac 1x$.

Comment: (i.e., $x\mapsto \sin\frac{1}{x}$ has bounded derivative on $[1,\infty)$. It will in particular be Lipschitz.)

Comment: Perhaps the problem was this:  Show that $f(x)=\sin x^{-1}$ is continuous, but not uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$.  That is a fairly common textbook problem at this level.

Answer (score 2):

If $1 \leq x < y$, then by mean-value theorem we have
$$
|\sin \frac{1}{x} - \sin \frac{1}{y}| \leq |x-y|\sup_{x \leq t \leq y}|\frac{\cos (1/t)}{t^{2}}| \leq |x-y|;
$$
hence the map $x \mapsto \sin (1/x): [1, \infty[ \to \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: This answer to the question (or rather to the correct version of the question) exploits the fact that Lipschitz functions are uniformly continuous.  Always a good idea to suspect whether this stronger condition holds.  You could also use the fact that a composition of uniformly continuous functions must be also uniformly continuous.